# Modify a plugin without changing it

Tags: arrays, wordpress, filter, plugins

I have copied below code from plugin, I just want to add another option in the array like 'option4' without changing the code in the plugin. I want to use child theme so that whenever plugin update my option will not be removed.

```
class my_class {
        private $var;
        protected function __construct() {
            add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register' ) );
        }
        public function register() {
            $this->var= apply_filters(
                'custom_plugin',
                array(
                    'option1' => 'value1',
                    'option2' => 'value2',
                    'option3' => 'value3',
                )
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is an `apply_filter` you can change it as follows:

```php
// use the filter name to add_filter
add_filter( 'custom_plugin', 'add_value_to_array' );

// Callback function which is getting the array value as its paramter.
function add_value_to_array( $array) {
    // Change/Add/Apend the value
    $array['option4'] = 'value4';
    // return it.
    return $array;
}
```

If you want to learn about it in detail I found a blog which you can go through : https://wpshout.com/apply_filters-do_action/

Comment: @TALHA, if this answer helped you consider marking as the correct answer.